# Fastest way to download data from GCS bucket

Tags: linux, shell-script, google-cloud

We have millions of files in some `GCS` bucket and I normally use `GSUTIL` to download some files based on some pattern to my local.

```
gsutil -m cp -R "gs://test-bucket-data-ingest/cm_data/AAA_AN/CM/*/a02_*_20210126*.csv.bz2" /home/xyz/testfiles/
```

I am running above on `Linux` server and get these files downloaded. It takes a lot of time to download it.

Thereafter, I unzip them and find an empty files.

```
bzip2 -d /home/xyz/testfiles/*
find . -name '*.csv' -size 0
```

Looking some fastest or more efficient way to download the files and also if we can combine all these commands into one script.. something parametrized kind.

`gsutil ls -l` works faster though.. Can we club it with some grep to get the list of only empty files and can download just those specific files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am posting this as an answer but new answers are always welcome.

`GSUTIL` with some pattern matching work really slow in case you have to search from millions or thousands of files. Its better to list them first and download the file using absolute file path.

```
vikrant_singh_rana@cloudshell:~/download$ cat download_gcs_file.sh
#!/bin/bash

#below code will delete the file if it already exists in the current working directory
file="ls_output.csv"

if [ -f "$file" ] ; then
    rm "$file"
fi
#below code will list the files to output file ls_output.csv based on search pattern
gsutil ls -l "gs://test-bucket-data-prod-ingest/cm_data/AN/AM/*/a01_*_20210128*.csv.bz2" | awk '!hdr{ print "filename"; hdr=1; }; $1 <= 100{ print $3; }' >ls_output.csv

input_file_path='/home/vikrant_singh_rana/download/ls_output.csv'

#below code will read the input file name and download it from gcs location to local
count=0

{
    read
    while IFS=, read -r inputfilename
    do

        echo "input filename is:"$inputfilename

        if [ ! -z "$inputfilename" ] || [ "$inputfilename" != "filename" ]
        then
        echo "downloading file:" $inputfilename
        gsutil -m cp -R "$inputfilename" /home/vikrant_singh_rana/download/output/

        else echo "No Empty Files found"
        fi

        count=$[count + 1]
        echo "count is:" $count
    done
} < $input_file_path

#below will unzip the files to csv format
bzip2 -d /home/vikrant_singh_rana/download/output/*
```

here was input file

```
vikrant_singh_rana@cloudshell:~/download$ cat ls_output.csv
filename
gs://test-bucket-data-prod-ingest/cm_data/AN/AM/172.24.105.197-CORE-2/a01_1h_255_XYZ_202101282300_0009.csv.bz2
```